# Entity Framework Core retrieving related entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to EFC and was hoping to get some help with a problem I ran into. 
Suppose I have two tables:

Tool table:

```
Version  FeatureId 

1         1

1         2

1         4

2         1
```

### Feature Table:

```
FeatureId Name

1         feature1

2         feature2

3         feature3

4         feature4
```

and based on these two tables I have the following:

```
public class Tool
{

public int Id {get; set;}

public int Version { get; set; } 

public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }

}

public class Feature
{

public string FeatureId { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

so a tool version may include more than one features and a feature may be included in more than one version. When I tried to retrieve a tool based on the version number like this:

```
_context.Tool.Where(x => x.Version == versionID)
           .Include(i => i.Features)
           .ToList()
```

I ran into an error asking for a ToolId. Why is that?

Comment: Try adding `public List<Tool> Tools { get; set; }` to your `Feature` class

Comment: @GuruStron, thanks. I got "Resolver error at paths./api/tool.get.responses.200.content.application/json.schema.properties.features.items.properties.tools.items.properties.features.items.$ref
Could not resolve reference: Not Found" in swagger if I added the list of tools as suggested.

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with EF =)

Answer (score 0):

> a tool version may include more than one features and a feature may be included in more than one version.

So you have many-to-many relashionship, and your tables must look like below:

```cs
public class Tool
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Version { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    public string FeatureId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tool> Tools { get; set; }
}
```

And the missed one:

```cs
public class ToolsFeatures
{
    public int ToolId { get; set; }
    public Tool Tool { get; set; }

    public int FeatureId { get; set; }
    public Feature Feature { get; set; }
}
```

Then configure the relashions the dbcontext:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ToolsFeatures>()
        .HasKey(t => new { t.ToolId, t.FeatureId});

        modelBuilder.Entity<ToolsFeatures>()
            .HasOne(t => t.Tool)
            .WithMany(f => f.Features)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.ToolId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ToolsFeatures>()
            .HasOne(f => f.Feature)
            .WithMany(t => t.Tools)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.FeatureId);
    }
```

See [Many-to-Many relashions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many)

---

Notice: You have `FeatureId` defined as `string` but it has `int` values! is there any mistake here?

Comment: Thanks! The FeatureId is a typo. Based on the post, instead of List<Tools> shouldn't it be List<ToolsFeatures> in Feature, and List<ToolsFeatures> not List<Features> in Tool? When I do:
modelBuilder.Entity<ToolsFeatures>()
            .HasOne(t => t.Tool)
            .WithMany(f => f.Features)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.ToolId);
I got an error at ' .WithMany(f => f.Features)': 
Cannot implicitly convert type '........List<Feature>' to '...IEnumerable<ToolsFeatures>'. Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type

Comment: Just replace the List<..> with ICollection<...> that was my mistake :)